# How to display html text in SVG?

Tags: html, svg

The following text

```
&amp;abc&#xff21;&#xff22;&#xff23;ä¸ä¸ƒÃ‡
```

is rendered in HTML as follows:

> &abcＡＢＣ丁七Ç

And in SVG it remains as in text:

```
&amp;abc&#xff21;&#xff22;&#xff23;丁七Ç
```

How can I make SVG render it correctly?

Comment: I formatted the code as code blocks, it was quite unreadable with all these dashes.  Please check if this is actually what you intended to write.

Comment: The suggestion on that post did not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ianscoding/mmupyx8k/ looks ok for me. If thats not what you are after, maybe post a jsfiddle ?